# How to define association relationship in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

**UPDATED**

I have a domain classes as below

```
class Training{
  // has one createdBy object references User domain and 
  // has one course object references Course domain
  // has One Trainer1 and Trainer2 objects refernces Trainer Object.
}

class Trainer{
   String name
  //can have many trainings.
  //If Trainer gets deleted, the trainings of him must be deleted
}
Class User{
  String name
  // can have many trainings. 
}

class Course{
  String name
   //If Course gets deleted, Trainings of this course must be deleted
   // can have many trainings.
}
```

I have got a training create page, Where I have to populate already saved Course, User, Trainer1 and Trainer2. I am not saving them while Creating the training.

So, How to specify the relationship in grails

Answer (score 1):

You did not put any effort to searching answer for yourslef. There are plenty basic examples and blog posts how to map relations in Grails. You should start with Grails documentation of GORM - Grails' object relational mapping. You can find it [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html).

Comment: Come on man. It is nice question with short answer. Comes handy when you forget about relationship definition and just want to have short snippet.

Comment: @MeIr - that's whaere documentation whit basic definitions comes in handy.

Comment: I agree with you. But when I googled it, stackoverflow came up first ;)

Answer (score 1):

I see some minor flaws in yout initial design: ie why should training be deleted if user is deleted when trainings will obviously tie with many users. Can training exists without trainers or vice versa ?

I would start with something like this:

```
Class Training {
    static hasMany = [users: User, trainers: Trainer]
    static belongsTo = Course
}

Class Trainer {
    String name
}

Class User {
   String name
}

Class Course {
    String name
    static hasMany = [trainings: Training]   
}
```

EDIT: I have to agree with Tomasz, you have jumped here too early without searching for answers yourself. Grails.org has good documentation about GORM with examples too.